# C++: Using loops and variable patterns (sequence)

Tags: c++, loops, variables

I have a routine function `process_letter_location(const char& c, string &word)`.

Inside my main I have declared a series of string variables like so:

```
string sf_1 = "something", sf_2 = "something", sf_3 = "something",
       sf_4 = "something";
```

And i have a `string word` and i call my routine function as so

```
process_letter_location(word[0], sf_1);
process_letter_location(word[1], sf_2);
process_letter_location(word[2], sf_3);
process_letter_location(word[3], sf_4);
```

This does look a bit messy but i know i can use a loop to call the routine like

```
for(int i=0; i < 4; i++) {
   process_letter_location (word[i], ?)
 }
```

But I'm not so sure how i would go about assigning the second argument. The variables have 'sf_' in common and the only thing that change are the numbers. Is there anyway that i can incorporate this routine call in the loop? If not are there better ways of implementing this code?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Don't declare what should be an array as separate variables?

Comment: Replace `string` with `const string&` in your function declaration/definition. Please.

Comment: `const char&` is useless. Copying a char is not an issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an array:

```
string sf[4] = { "something1", "something2", "something3", "something4"};
```

Then loop:

```
for(int i=0; i < 4; i++) {
   process_letter_location (word[i], sf[i]);
 }
```

Comment: Let the compiler count: `string sf[4]` --> `string sf[]`

Comment: Also `const string sf[]` if you are not going to change the strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this refactoring: replace `string` with `string * const` 
in the function `process_letter_location`. (Adjust the function definition
accordingly).

Then you can fill your favourite container with the string pointers 
and loop on it.

I think you can learn a lot of C++ from this refactoring.

Let me show how you could write the loop:

```
std::vector<std::string*> strings = {&sf_1, 
                                     &sf_2,
                                     &sf_3,
                                     &sf_4};

for(int i=0; i < 4; i++) {
    process_letter_location (word[i], strings[i]);
        }
```

then you may consider using iterators rather than a C-style loop.

Comment: Yea my actual implementation has const  and pass by references to it. I just wanted to focus on the variable thing :)

Comment: Sorry, but *not* having `const` and pass by reference is the distraction.  It makes us stop and go "wait! what? why isn't that by const ref?".

Answer (score 0):

You *should* use an array. Your use case *screams* it should be an array.
But if you can only change how you process the variables, you can use a variadic template function as well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

void process_letter_location(char c, string const& str)
{
    cout << str << '\n';
}

void process_strings(char* buf, string const& str)
{
    process_letter_location(*buf, str);
}

template<typename... Args>
auto process_strings(char* buf, string const& str, Args... args)
  -> typename enable_if<sizeof...(Args)>::type
{
    process_letter_location(*buf, str);
    process_strings (++buf, args...);
}


int main() {
    string sf_1 = "something1",
           sf_2 = "something2",
           sf_3 = "something3",
           sf_4 = "something4"; 

    char buff[10];
    process_strings(buff, sf_1, sf_2, sf_3, sf_4);
    return 0;
}
```

Which is just a fancy way to unroll the loop. [See here](http://ideone.com/MzKpof)

Comment: 1. You need to increment `buf` in your recursive template.  2.  A simpler way to fit the constraints you have would be:  const string* sf[] = { &sf_1, &sf_2, ...};    and then in the loop `process_letter_location(buff[i], *sf[i]);`

Comment: @MartinBonner, 1) I noted and fixed that as you were typing. 2) Like I said in the first two sentences, this is overkill. But it's another way to get it done.

Comment: Oh wow okay. I never knew about this method. Will look into it thank you :)

Comment: @NihasNebas, consider the array + loop method instead. I just posted it for completeness (and because it was fun to devise).